# Extending several button classes in Foundation does not inherit their hover state

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, zurb-foundation, compass-sass

(This is really hard to explain) I am trying to create a new button class in Foundation like this:

```
.btn {
  @extend .button;
  @extend .small;
  @extend .radius;
  @extend .secondary;
}
```

It works fine and gets all the parent styles, except the `hover` state ones.
For example consider these:

```
<a href="button small secondary radius disabled" href="#">A button</a>
<!-- hover color is gray -->
```

and

```
<a href="btn disabled" href="#">A button</a>
<!-- hover color is white, but it should be gray -->
```

I tried this, but it didn't worked:

```
.btn {
  @extend .button;
  @extend .small;
  @extend .radius;
  @extend .secondary;
  .disabled {
    @extend .disabled;
  }
}
```

I am using the zurb-foundation gem with Rails 3.2.9.
Any idea how to fix it?

**EDIT**

Here is the generated CSS:

```
.button.disabled, .disabled.btn, .btn .btn.disabled, .btn .button.disabled, .button[disabled], [disabled].btn {
  opacity: 0.6;
  cursor: default;
  background: #2ba6cb;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.button.disabled :hover, .disabled.btn :hover, .button[disabled] :hover, [disabled].btn :hover {
  background: #2ba6cb;
}

.button.disabled.success, .disabled.success.btn, .button[disabled].success, [disabled].success.btn {
  background-color: #5da423;
}

.button.disabled.success:hover, .disabled.success.btn:hover, .button.disabled.success:focus, .disabled.success.btn:focus, .button[disabled].success:hover, [disabled].success.btn:hover, .button[disabled].success:focus, [disabled].success.btn:focus {
  background-color: #5da423;
  outline: none;
}

.button.disabled.alert, .disabled.alert.btn, .button[disabled].alert, [disabled].alert.btn {
  background-color: #c60f13;
}

.button.disabled.alert:hover, .disabled.alert.btn:hover, .button.disabled.alert:focus, .disabled.alert.btn:focus, .button[disabled].alert:hover, [disabled].alert.btn:hover, .button[disabled].alert:focus, [disabled].alert.btn:focus {
  background-color: #c60f13;
  outline: none;
}

.button.disabled.secondary, .disabled.btn, .btn .btn.disabled, .button[disabled].secondary, [disabled].btn {
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
}

.button.disabled.secondary:hover, .disabled.btn:hover, .button.disabled.secondary:focus, .disabled.btn:focus, .button[disabled].secondary:hover, [disabled].btn:hover, .button[disabled].secondary:focus, [disabled].btn:focus {
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
  outline: none;
}
```

Comment: I created a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/zr3bM/), but I don't see what you're seeing.  Both items show up with a grey background no matter what.  Is that a direct copy/paste from the HTML?  You have 2 `href` attributes instead of 1 `class` and 1 `href` (I fixed those in the fiddle).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling for a while, I managed to solve it this way:

```
.btn {
  @extend .button;
  @extend .secondary;
  @extend .radius;
  @extend .small;
  &.disabled {
    @extend .button;
    @extend .disabled;
}
```

Now it gives me the right ouput!

Answer (score 0):

If what you are going for is a short cut for `button small secondary radius` then why don't you extend just that? It should produce a cleaner output.

```
.btn
{
    @extend .button.small.secondary.radius;
}
```

Also make sure your custom CSS is referenced after foundation.css something could be overriding you.